# Basis-independent proof that $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$ for subspace of finite dimensional space

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

Let $V$ be a linear subspace of a finite-dimensional inner-product space $U$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Does there exist a basis-independent proof  that $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$?

I would preferably like a proof in a more categorical way, i.e., without reference to the elements of the vector spaces at al.

Comment: No, because the statement is not true in general, and you need the finite dimensionality, which is a concept that requires basis (or at least a finite generating set).

Comment: Would you accept a proof that counts dimensions?

Comment: The notation $V^\perp$ might need explanation, at least I wouldn't be completely sure what is meant by it.  I suspect you mean $V^\perp$ to be the subspace consisting of those $f \in U^*$ vanishing on $V$?

Comment: Did you mean to assume that $U$ is an inner product space, in order to make sense of $\perp$?

Comment: Ah sorry, I did assume a non-degenerate bilinear (or sesquilinear) form is given. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @KennyLau If it would not use a basis or reference to specific elements then yes.

Comment: Would you accept a proof in these lines? "Let $p: U \to U$ be the orthogonal projection to $V$, so that $V^\perp = \ker p$. Then $1-p: U \to U$ is the orthogonal projection to $\ker p$, so $(V^\perp)^\perp = \ker(1-p) = \operatorname{im}(p) = V$."

Comment: The two (potential) problems I can see are (1) how to construct $p$ and (2) why is "orthogonal projection to [subspace]" unique